# measuring print job time programmatically

Tags: vbscript

I need to measure print job time, which means time between 'send print command' and 'print job disappear from the print queue'

so I am trying to do these things by script

1. search all pdf files
2. print a file
3. get the print time (as above)
4. go to next file and do all above for all files

this is my work so far(i omit some parts)

```
For Each file In objFolder.Items
'   check for the extension
    if objFSO.GetExtensionName(file.name) = "pdf" then
'       invoke to print 
        file.InvokeVerbEx( "Print" )
'       select print jobs
        Set Printers =  objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_PrintJob")

        For Each objPrinter in Printers     
            DateTime.Value = objPrinter.TimeSubmitted
            TimeinQueue = DateDiff("n", actualTime, Now)
            Wscript.Echo TimeinQueue
        Next
    end if
next
```

mainly i need to ask how can i get the time when print job disappear from the print queue.

And I need to keep next job till one print job ends. 
any ideas ?

Comment: Could help `Win32_PrintJob` Class in the `\root\CIMV2` NameSpace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for exact thing and I simply summurized ansgar's script to get what I want.
its take every pdf files and print 5 times each(so i can get a avarage which better) while getting the time.finally print them in to a csv file. and untill one going to desapear from the print queue others wait waits. Not 100% acuurate but enough for the perfomance comparision 
may be it may usefull (please correct my mistakes if any)

```
Dim objFSO, outFile
const forAppending = 8
const useDefault = -2

'Output File name
fileName = ".\output.csv"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set outFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(fileName, forAppending, true, useDefault)

'write heading to output file
outFile.WriteLine("Filename,1,2,3,4,5")

'get current Folder
strFolder = Replace(wscript.scriptfullname,wscript.scriptname,".\")
strFolder = objFSO.getFolder(strFolder)

'Open the Shell Folders object
Set objShell  = CreateObject( "Shell.Application" )

'Create an object for the specified file's parent folder
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace( strFolder )

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

For Each file In objFolder.Items
  If objFSO.GetExtensionName(file.name) = "pdf" Then
    'write in to out file
    outFile.write(file.name)
    outFile.writeLine ""

    'outer loop for 5 times per each file
    index = 0
    do while index < 5
      'if already doing a printing do not start a new one
      if CheckPrintQueue() = 0 then
         file.InvokeVerbEx "Print"
         startTime = timer
         waitTostart
      'if first time on outer loop it should be empty queue
      else 
        if index = 0 then 
          wscript.echo "queue doesnt empty"
          finish
        end if
      end if
      'wait until all jobs finished printing
      waitToEnd
      'count time
      ellapsTime = timer - startTime
      'write in to out file   
      outFile.write(",")
      outFile.Write(ellapsTime)   
      index = index + 1
    loop
  End If
Next

outFile.Close
'----------------function CheckPrintQueue-----------------------
Function CheckPrintQueue()
  Set printJobs = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PrintJob")
  Set currentDocs = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

  CheckPrintQueue = printJobs.Count
End Function
'----------------end of function-----------------

sub waitTostart
  Do 
    WScript.Sleep 100
    'check print queue
    printJobCount = CheckPrintQueue()
  Loop until printJobCount > 0
end sub

sub waitToEnd
  Do 
    WScript.Sleep 100
    'check print queue
    printJobCount = CheckPrintQueue()
  Loop until printJobCount = 0
end sub

sub finish
  outFile.Close
  objFSO = nothing
  objFolder = nothing
  objShell = nothing
  objWMIService = nothing
  wscript.quit 1
end sub
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no simple way to obtain that information from inside your script, because when the job is removed from the print queue it's gone. You could set up an event monitor for the print spooler like this:

```
Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")
Set wbemDateTime = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")

qry = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN 1 " & _
      "WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_PrintJob'"
Set mon = wmi.ExecNotificationQuery(qry)

Do
  Set evt = mon.NextEvent
  If evt.Path_.Class = "__InstanceDeletionEvent" Then
    wbemDateTime.Value = evt.TargetInstance.TimeSubmitted
    WScript.Echo evt.TargetInstance.Document & ": " & _
                 DateDiff("n", wbemDateTime.GetVarDate, Now)
  End If
Loop
```

However, you'd have to run that from a different script, because VBScript doesn't support multi-threading (i.e. running things in parallel), so the event handler loop would block the rest of your script operations.

If you want a rough value from within your script, you could try something like this, but don't expect queue times to be very accurate:

```
'singleton SWbemDateTime instance for time conversions
Set wbemDateTime = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")

'global list to keep track of printing documents
'MUST NOT BE MODIFIED FROM ANYWHERE EXCEPT CheckPrintQueue!
Set printingDocs = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Function CheckPrintQueue
  Set printJobs = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PrintJob")
  Set currentDocs = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

  'get currently printing jobs from queue
  For Each job In printJobs
    currentDocs.Add job.Document, job.TimeSubmitted
  Next

  'compare global list to current list, print the queue time for documents
  'that are no longer queued, and remove them from the global list
  For Each doc In printingDocs.Keys
    If Not currentDocs.Exists(doc) Then
      wbemDateTime.Value = printingDocs(doc)
      WScript.Echo doc & ": " & DateDiff("n", wbemDateTime.GetVarDate, Now)
      printingDocs.Remove doc
    End If
  Next

  'add new documents to global list
  For Each doc In currentDocs.Keys
    If Not printingDocs.Exists(doc) Then printingDocs.Add doc, currentDocs(doc)
  Next

  CheckPrintQueue = printJobs.Count
End Function

For Each file In objFolder.Items
  If objFSO.GetExtensionName(file.name) = "pdf" Then
    file.InvokeVerbEx "Print"
    CheckPrintQueue
  End If
Next

'wait until all jobs finished printing
Do While CheckPrintQueue > 0
  WScript.Sleep 100
Loop
```

Comment: Thank you. but im little confuse about 'CheckPrintJobs' at last loop should it be 'CheckPrintQueue' ?

Comment: @mhs Indeed it should. Fixed.